# CURL not validating certifcate

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate

We use curl as part of a script to download firmware updates from our site.  The link on our site is actually a redirect to the most current version of the firmware on an S3 bucket.  I have tried using curl with the S3 url; that works.  Our site is a load balanced site running on an AWS EC2 load balancer with two instances.  A CHAINED certficate with GoDaddy as the issuer is installed on our load balancer AND the NGINX hosted instances.  Below is the chain as viewed from Chrome.

[image: From Chrome]

BUT, I get the standard certificate validation error message when curl-ing the firmware update from our URL

```
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: 
/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

Our firmware distribution is bitbaked for an ARM processor with 256MB flash, it comes with curl built in for it, and a fairly sizable "mozilla + ca_certs" installation of CA certificates in /usr/share/ca-certificates and /etc/ca-certificates.conf.  These clearly had update-ca-certificates run on the bitbake - there is a 1-1 match in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Our site certificate has the following output from openssl's decode:

```
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    Validity
        Not Before: Jul  1 21:02:38 2016 GMT
        Not After : Sep 29 21:02:38 2019 GMT .......
 ......
             X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
            keyid:40:C2:BD:27:8E:CC:34:83:30:A2:33:D7:FB:6C:B3:F0:B4:2C:80:CE

        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            DNS:*.ourdomain.com
        X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
            A2:CE:7F:D5:B2:51:2C:B1:D4:FF:34:A1:9C:B3:AF:C4:29:34:1A:FF
```

Now, as you saw before, the certificate chain for our site includes THREE Go Daddy certificates.  The subject key identifiers of the four certs in our chain are:

```
root: D2:C4:B0:D2:91:D4:4C:11:71:B3:61:CB:3D:A1:FE:DD:A8:6A:D4:E3
second: 3A:9A:85:07:10:67:28:B6:EF:F6:BD:05:41:6E:20:C1:94:DA:0F:DE
third: 40:C2:BD:27:8E:CC:34:83:30:A2:33:D7:FB:6C:B3:F0:B4:2C:80:CE
OURS: A2:CE:7F:D5:B2:51:2C:B1:D4:FF:34:A1:9C:B3:AF:C4:29:34:1A:FF
```

The top in the chain EXACTLY matches the Go_Daddy_Class_2_CA.crt certificate in our distribution.  The SECOND from the top certificate in our site chain matches the "Subject Key Identifier" in our distributions "Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.crt" file in the mozilla certificates.  HOWEVER, that file in our distribution does NOT seem to be chained to the the class 2 CA by way of the "Authority Key Identifier" The third certificate in the chain doesn't exist at all in the included certs!

SO, I took the second from the top in our chained certificate and REPLACED that file on our distribution.  I also put the third certificate in the chain on the distribution to begin with, so now all the GoDaddy certificates seemed to be represented.  I put these in the /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla directory, and made sure all the entries were represented in /etc/ca-certificates.conf file.  I then ran "update-ca-certificates"

This, I verified, put the new certificates into /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt file, and when I run

```
curl --verbose --location https://ourdomain.com/location
* found 158 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-
certificates.crt CRLfile: none
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed.
```

The 158 certificates was the requisite increase from adding our certificate to the mix. As I've said before, I've tried everything from using --cacert directly, to the article which didn't work because there isn't a trusted db of certs on the box.  The download directly from a secure amazon URL worked fine, but we don't want to have to tell customers new URLs, so we'd like to have the redirect from our site.

So, for SSL over CURL experts, what am I missing?

UPDATE: curl works for this URL on a Linux Mint VM with literally the same certficate list file with this output.

```
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.ourdomain.com
*    start date: 2016-07-01 21:02:38 GMT
*    expire date: 2019-09-29 21:02:38 GMT
*    subjectAltName: support.ourdomain.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; 
OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate 
Authority - G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /download/firmware HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: support.ourdomain.com
> Accept: */*
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curl command worked on our firmware when I applied an individual IP of one of the load balanced servers to /etc/hosts for ourdomain.com.  I then went to the load balancer on AWS and re-applied the certificate with the full chain to the load balancer.  Once that was done, the curl command worked even without a hosts entry.  So the certificate was improperly applied on the load balancer, but somehow browsers (and the more full featured curl on the VM) saw past that and got the right certificate, but the version on our firmware didn't.